# Load Unpacked Chrome Extension not working

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm getting started on my first extension using the Chrome tutorial and got tripped up almost immediately. Says to click Load Unpacked and then select the file path to the manifest file. However, when I click Load Unpacked nothing shows up; no file explorer or even an error message. There's no change to the screen. Any understanding on why this might be happening?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the browser is or its access to file system is completely denied. Try a portable version of Chrome or Chrome Canary or contact your IT/domain administrator.

Comment: An alternative method (assuming the "developer mode" is enabled in the top right corner of chrome://extensions page) is to simply drag'n'drop the **directory** of the extension's manifest.json into chrome://extensions page.

Comment: See also [Load unpacked Chrome extension programmatically](//stackoverflow.com/a/20784332)

Comment: It might be disabled by your organization as in my case. Try it on your personal laptop, then it will work

Answer (score 3):

RegEdit:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\ExtensionInstallBlocklist
```

Then remove * from 1 and restart Chrome.

Bingo, can add Extensions...

Answer (score 1):

Go to chrome://policy/ and check if the ExtensionInstallBlacklist policy has been set.

If it is, then ask your friendly admin if they can please update the policy.

[Update] Open Dev Tools (F12) and check under console. If you see a policy error, then you know the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

`strace` may be of value here. First, `pstree -p` to find the root PID of chrome or chromium. Then `strace -f -s256 -v -p $CHROMEPID -o/tmp/chrome.strace.log`, where CHROMEPID is the PID you found in the first step.

I was having a similar problem, however I *did* get a file explorer and was able to navigate to the extension directory, but then I couldn't figure out how to actually enable it; nothing showed up in the directory itself to click on. On the bottom was only "Select Folder". But then I tried maximizing the window (in the fluxbox taskbar, right-clicked the name of the window and selected Maximize), then I found the "Cancel" and "Open" buttons below "Select Folder". Clicking Open on the folder from one level up did the trick.

I know this won't likely help the OP but maybe it will help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have an extension with the exact same name installed from the Web Store.
In the past, you could have two versions of the same extension installed side by side, one from the store and one loaded unpacked. In the past few months, that changed.