# Which policy blocks loading unpacked Chrome extensions?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to load an unpacked chrome extension. When I click the *Load unpacked* button nothing happens; [much the same as this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58697679/load-unpacked-chrome-extension-not-working). I am working within a system that has extension instalation control policies, particulary a `ExtensionInstallBlacklist` of `*` and a list of whitelisted extensions. No other policies seem to impact extensions.

It turns out that there's a js error in the console when I click the button:

```
Error handling response: Error: Extension installation is blocked by policy.
at chrome://extensions/crisper.js:215:2522
```

but looking at the js that this leads to doesn't give any clues about the name of the policy. I have searched the [Chrome Enterprise policy list](https://cloud.google.com/docs/chrome-enterprise/policies/) without any luck.

What *is* the policy that's blocking this?

Comment: Have you looked into [this](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7532015?hl=en)? It's Google support forum about configuring extension installation policies.

Comment: I've read this, as far as I can tell, it doesn't mention controling loading of unpacked extensions.

Comment: You can copypaste `"key"` from manifest.json of an **installed** allowed extension (in the browser profile directory) into your own so your extension's id will be of that extension.

Comment: @wOxxOm, how would this work? The button to load unpacked is blocked. Does this need to be done from the command line?

Comment: Hopefully. I didn't check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ExtensionInstallBlacklist`](https://cloud.google.com/docs/chrome-enterprise/policies/?policy=ExtensionInstallBlacklist)

> A blacklist value of '*' means all extensions are blacklisted unless they are explicitly listed in the whitelist.

This includes unpacked extensions, otherwise the user could easily circumvent the enterprise policy.

Comment: That makes sense when you put it like that!